# Unable to Discover My Scanner

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth

I want to connect my scanner with my app via Bluetooth , for that i referred this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor , but here i added my uuid but it is not discovering my scanner, please help me to discover my scanner 
here is the coding which i have tried based on tutorial :

UUID :00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BLE_Devices]];
CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];  
self.centralManager = centralManager;
```

}

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
// Determine the state of the peripheral
if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
}
else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
    NSLog(@"%@",self.services);

    [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.services options:nil];

}
else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
}
else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
}
else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
}}
```

//- This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
NSLog(@"%@ The adverstisementData is:",advertisementData);

if ([localName length ]> 0)
{

//if (![localName isEqual:@""]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ Local Name:",localName);
    // We found the Heart Rate Monitor
    [self.centralManager stopScan];
    self.polarH7HRMPeripheral = peripheral;
    peripheral.delegate = self;
    [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}}
```

centralManagerDidUpdateState: method is working fine ,
Please help me to connect with my scanner .

[image: Please see here ,my scanner is connected via bluetooth in my iPod touch]

Comment: `[central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil]` find your scanner? Is LightBlue.app find your scanner ? Is your device really Bluetooth Low-Energy ?

Comment: thanks ,@Larme ,i have tried services:nil , not getting , but sometime i got different UUID .UUID is "FFF0".Now i am trying with light blue app

Comment: Can u please , tell me how to use LightBlue app . i have created virtual peripherals name as Scan Parameters,and UUId as Scanners UUId ,Whether it is correct or not

Comment: With Lightblue.app don't create a virtual device, just check if you can find your scanner. With services nil, what's the `advertisementData` when you find your scanner?

Comment: LightBlue app showing "Searching for peripherals "only till now

Comment: What's your scanner? Is it really Bluetooth Low-Energy?

Comment: Ya . i can able to connect my scanner using bluetooth in my iPod touch

Comment: Bluetooth is different from Bluetooth Low-Energy. Please clarify.

Comment: Please see my update question , i have attached my screenshot that scanner is connected with my iPod touch

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. What's your scanner model? What says the doc about it? Is it really Bluetooth Low-Energy (which I doubt, and that's why you can't find it with CoreBluetooth which is ONLY for Bluetooth Low-Energy, and not "classical Bluetooth") ?

Comment: @Larme,I am using 2d Wearable Scanner , whether it is Bluetooth Low Energy or not ?

Comment: Do you have a link for that scanner?

Comment: http://www.posunitech.com/products_detail/&productId=96.html

Comment: It's not clear, but if you never paired with a device, and you can find it in Settings.app/Bluetooth, it's not a Bluetooth Low-Energy device.

Comment: @Larme , is there any other chance to connect the Non Bluetooth Low energy Devices to my app

Comment: If it's MFi (Made For iPhone), you can use ExternalAccessory.framework.

Comment: Thanks @Larme , Please share any tutorial link for that ,it will be very useful to me